# For what $a \in \Bbb R$ does $\neg(3a>21\implies a \leq 5)$ hold?

Tags: logic

For what $a\in\mathbb{R}$ will the statement $\neg(3a>21\implies a\leq 5)$ hold?

My gut feeling says $a>7$, but I do not know how to formally write it down or prove it. Can someone help me?

Comment: I suppose you know that that $\neg (A \implies B)$ if and only iff $A \land \neg B$? If you apply this and simplify $3a > 21$, you have an almost complete proof that this is equivalent to $a>7$...

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Please, try to make the title of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a\le b$ imply $a+c\le b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* For more information on choosing a good title, see [this post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144).

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{align}
\neg(3a>21\implies a\leq 5) & \;\equiv\; \neg(a \leq 5 \;\lor\; \neg(3a > 21)) \\
& \;\equiv\; \neg(a \leq 5) \;\land\; 3a > 21 \\
& \;\equiv\; a > 5  \;\land\; a > 7 \\
& \;\equiv\; a > 7
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

First note that $\neg(3a>21\implies a\le 5)$ is true exactly when $3a>21\implies a\le 5$ is false, so you really need to determine when $3a>21\implies a\le 5$ is false. I expect that you know that an implication $p\implies q$ is false if and only if $p$ is true and $q$ is false; in all other cases it’s true. Thus, we want to know for which values of $a$ the statement $3a>21$ is true **and** the statement $a\le 5$ is false. Now $3a>21$ is true exactly when then $a>\frac{21}3=7$; and whenever that’s the case, $a\le 5$ is certainly false. So for what values of $a$ is

$$\neg(3a>21\implies a\le 5)$$

true?